# Awesome WM not appearing on login

Tags: lubuntu, window-manager, awesome

I've installed **awesome wm** on **lubuntu 16.04** but it doesn't appear as one of the choices at login screen.

Here's the content of my `/usr/share/xsessions/awesome.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=awesome
Comment=Highly configurable framework window manager
TryExec=awesome
Type=Application
Exec=awesome
```

I've tried adding **NoDisplay=false**, yet it does nothing.
Hope you can help me out here.

Comment: What was the command you used to install it?

Comment: @DKBose i installed it w/ apt-get

`apt get install awesome`

Comment: What does `which awesome` show?

Comment: it outputs `/usr/bin/awesome`

Comment: 1: maybe you could edit the .desktop file Exec and TryExec lines to include `/usr/bin/`. 2: which other login options do you see?

Comment: By the way, if you search the internet for "awesome wm not appearing as login option" you'll get many hits!

Comment: I've been searching for a half an hour already but almost everything i've found was just remove `NoDisplay=true` is it's specified on the awesome.desktop.

Comment: I've already tried adding `TryExec=/usr/bin/awesome` but still no success

Comment: Have you tried asking at a forum dedicated to awesome? Maybe someone there will walk you through what needs to be done, if at all that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to reboot your system, I just had that issue installing logging out. A full reboot fixed it for me.